# What should I do to get a binary tree from a file in c++?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, fstream

I have a text file which contained something like:

```
\*a\*b\*cd
```

and I want to get a binary tree like:

```
       *
      / \
     a   *
        / \
       b   *
          / \
         c   d
```

Thanks for reminding, the rule is:

`\*` could be regarded as just one symbol which represents the parent node who has two children. Two children are the characters behind the `\*` when the first one is the left child and the latter one is the right child. The alphabetic characters represent the node without any child. So, the first `\*` means the start of the tree. Then the `a` means the left child of the first `\*` is an `a` without any child. Then the `\*` means the right child of the first `\*` is a `\*` who has two children.

What I have done is:(I've made some change to my code)

```
struct Tree {
    char data;
    Tree *left;
    Tree *right;
};

void print(Tree *root) {
    if (root) {
        print(root->right);
        cerr << root->data << endl;
        print(root->left);
    }
}

Tree * maketree(ifstream &ifs) {
    Tree *p = new Tree(); 
    int b;
    while((b=ifs.get())!=EOF){
        char a = b;
        if(a == '*'){
            continue;
        }
        if(a != '\\'){
            p->data = a;
            p->left = p->right = NULL;
        }
        else  {
            p->data = '*';
            p->left = maketree(ifs);
            p->right = maketree(ifs);
        }
    }
    return p;
}

int main() {

    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open("test.txt");
    assert(ifs.good());

    Tree *root = maketree(ifs);

    ifs.close();

    print(root);

    return 0;
}
```

I made some change to my code again,
finally it works, but the result printed is very weird......

It gives me:

```
*

*

*
d
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the reason and the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: `I'm not sure \* could be regarded as a single character`. Your right, this is a string of length 2. So your comparison can't work.

Comment: `'\'` will give you grief. Needs escaping. `(a=ifs.get())!=EOF` with `char a;` may give you trouble `EOF` isn't a `char`

Comment: @kebs Thanks for reminding, I've fixed this problem.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes! u r right, EOF should be an integer!

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand how the tree specification in the text file results in the picture you've drawn? I couldn't find a consistent set of rules. I have a hypothesis, you can see if that makes sense, but it deviates in the final output from what you've mentioned.

Here is my hypothesis:
The \ indicates that all the left children of a previous node have been added, and the next entry is child of the parent of this node whose children finished being added.
In your example:

```
\*a\*b\*cd
```

1. The first \ represents the start of the tree.
2. The * after that is the first child.
3. The a after that is the child of the *
4. The \ after a indicates that all the children of a have been added and the next entry will be a child of the parent of a
5. The * which comes next is a child of the first *
6. Then b is a child of the second *
7. Then \ indicates that all children of b have been added
8. The next * is a child of the second *
9. Then the c is a child of the third *
10. Then the d is the second child of the third *

What I couldn't figure out is, how you would represent a Node with only a right child in this representation.

Based on what I mentioned, your diagram would look like:

```
   *
  / \
 a   *
    / \
   b   *
      /
     c
    /
   d
```

Writing code for this should be easier since the rules seem more consistent. You would keep adding left children till you hit a '\' at which point you traverse one node up, if the next symbol is still a '\' you go further up, otherwise you add a right child.

Comment: I think `\*` could be regarded as just one symbol which represents the parent node who have two children. Two children are the characters behind the `\*` when the first one is the left child and the latter one is the right child. The alphabetic characters represent the node without any child.  So, the first `\*` means the start of the tree. Then the `a`means the left child of the first `\*` is `a` without any child. Then the `\*` means the right child of the first `\*` is a `\*` who has two children.

Comment: Do only \* nodes have 2 children?